# How can I change the .NET framework used by LogiXML?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, regedit

Ok, I have LogiXML and I need to use its "Scheduler for Java". When I use it I get an ASP.NET error and at the bottom of the page I can see that Logi is using ASP.NET version 2. I have installed the version 4 of .NET using the installer dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe but I cannot get Logi to use this version. I can see the RegEdit is using version 2 also, please help me to figure out how to change the .NET version or how to repair this Logi issue

Comment: Ok, I have LogiXML and I need to use its "Scheduler for Java". When I use it I get an ASp.NET error and at the bottom of the page I can see that Logi is using ASP.NET version 2. I have installed the version 4 of .NET using the installer dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe but I can not get Logi uses this version. I can see the RegEdit is using version 2 also, please help me to figure out how to change the .NET version. or how to repair this Logi issue

Comment: My guess is that you need to change the version of the .NET framework used by your app pool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523(v=WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For questions about LogiXML, check out LogiXML DevNet at http://devnet.logixml.com.